# How to assign a unique ID to date-picker fields on django form?

Tags: django, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using `django-bootstrap3` (`pip install django-bootstrap3`) third party application to render forms. I am using `django-bootstrap-datepicker` (`pip install django-bootstrap-datepicker`) application to apply widget calendar.

In the following form, I have two fields: `check_in` and `check_out`
which I want apply the date-picker to together

```
from bootstrap_datepicker.widgets import DatePicker
class DateInput(DatePicker):
    def __init__(self):
        DatePicker.__init__(self,format="%Y-%m-%d")
    def build_attrs(self, attrs, extra_attrs=None, **kwargs):
        attrs = dict(self.attrs, **kwargs)
        if extra_attrs:
            attrs.update(extra_attrs)
        return attrs

class LodgingOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'check_in': DateInput(),
            'check_out': DateInput(),
        }
        model = LodgingOffer
        fields = ('other fields', 'check_in', 'check_out', )
```

On the html template I am rendering the forms of this way, including `form.media` to accept js and css effects of `bootstrap-datepicker`:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block body_content %}

{% block extrahead %}   {# Extra Resources Start #}
   {{ form.media }}        {# Form required JS and CSS #}
{% endblock %}

{% bootstrap_field form.check_in %}
{% bootstrap_field form.check_out %}
{% endblock %}
```

And when I try render my form, the date-picker effect it's only apply to first field rendered in the form, this means that the just `check_in` field has the date-picker effect and `check_out` field does not have it.

- Check in field

[image]

- Check out field

[image]

**UPDATE**

I perform an inspect in my browser and I found that `check_in` and `check_out` fields have the same id `_pickers` and the JS code call to the first `_pickers`  that found.

- Check in
  [image]
- Check out
  [image]

How to can I modify the id of each field with the order to widget works to together fields?

Comment: Did you try using onChange in jQuery for your date inputs?

Comment: @abybaddi009 I still don't tried that alternative.  I have read and apply

Comment: @abybaddi009 I think so that the onChange is not the appropiated alternative to address this. I don't want select some option or see some output based in a previous action. How to could I work with onChange in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the id `pickers` of this way:

```
class LodgingOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'check_in': DateInput(),
            'check_out': forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker2'}),

            'country': CountrySelectWidget(),
        }
        model = LodgingOffer
        fields = ('check_in', 'check_out', )
```

And in my template I override or call the `datepicker` function of this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            sideBySide: true,
           // format: 'DD.MM.YYYY' 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Of this way I can see the different ids and my calendar picker works in together fields

[image]